# Validation rule - Regex to find if the 4th character in a text field is a hyphen

Tags: validation-rule

Playing around with regex, got most of it right, but just one part,not able to make it work.
How to check with regex if the 4th character in a text field is a hyphen.

```
NOT(REGEX(MID(field__c,4,4), "[/-/]"))
```

EDIT
Tried the below as a validation rule, I was able to save a record with de4-3456, which shouldn't happen. the DEF shouldn't care if it is in lower or caps.

```
NOT(REGEX(field__c, "DEF-.+"))
&&
NOT(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(field__c,4)))
```

Comment: Since you are slicing the text anyway, why do you need to use regex? I suggest `NOT(REGEX(Jira_Number__c, "...-.+"))`

Comment: I was fiddling with this too... looks like the REGEX function only works on a whole match. So that's good to know. ie, `^.{3}-[\s\S]*` works, but `^.{3}-` doesnt

Comment: @PhilW Thank you. Please add it as an answer

Comment: @PhilW Could you check my original post, I tried your code with a variation, for some reason it doesn't seem to be validating.

Comment: Jira issue numbers are not fixed 4 digit values which will cause you problems. To check that the value is a prefix, a hyphen followed by a number use regex like `.{2,3}-[0-9]{1,5}` to allow for 2 or three character prefix, a hyphen then between 1 and 5 numeric digits.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW, that worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira issue numbers are not fixed 4 digit values which will cause you problems. To check that the value is a prefix, a hyphen followed by a number use regex like `.{2,3}-[0-9]{1,5}` to allow for 2 or three character prefix, a hyphen then between 1 and 5 numeric digits.

You might like to actually use `[A-Za-z]{2,3}-[0-9]{1,5}` as the regex if you always use upper or lower case latin alphabet characters for the issue prefix.